# Connect grails front with java REST backend

Tags: java, grails, frontend, backend

I have Java backend project with REST implementation which is a warfile, 
  I also have Grails as frontend, i can run theese two separeted projects on their own using tomcat,

but how do i configure the grails part so that i can use the java backend RESTfull webbservice within it,

do i have to make a war file from the java backend and import it to the grails frontend ?  make a jarfile ?

if so, how do i do that ?   or are there any other way to to this to make it work.

Comment: ou said that you already have 'grails as frontend' and you 'can run theese projects'. So, what actually you're trying to reach, if everything is working already as you said?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/565590/Groovy/grails-frontend-Java-REST-backend

Comment: Is your question about how to have a grails web app talk to another web app providing a REST interface, or how to run two tomcat instances from two different IDE's at the same time as your comments to the answers seems to indicate? If the latter, perhaps start a new question. I believe both have been answered in direct answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

REST provides a way to access a service without having to link them explicitly.

RESTful applications use HTTP requests to post data (create = HTTP-POST, update = HTTP-PUT, read = HTTP-GET, delete = HTTP-DELETE

If you run the Java backend using Tomcat, can you access it from a browser?
i.e.
http://localhost:8080/backendservice/resource/1
(this will be a GET request.)

You need to make the http requests from your application.

Comment: Yes i can acces it fom the browser but, how will my grails app  communicate with my RESTful app in eclipse?  both apps require tomcat. How Should i make the RESTapp to work when grails app is calling it., how do i set up and configure grails with dependency? or jar ? Restfull app is made as war .

Comment: I think you need to read up on how to use REST.  http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2477 (though it's a little old) Basically, you need to construct an http request for the resource you want - i.e. to read data.  You then make that request, and read the response back - it will probably be json or xml.  You then parse that for the information you want

Comment: yeah maybee, i know the REStapp is working but when i try to communicate from the STS with it i get: Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use, and i suppose i have to start the server in eclipse in order for the REST app to work right ?

Comment: what port does the back end run on, and what port does your grails app run on?  Shouldn't matter where you run the service from...

Comment: i am using one IDE  STS for grails app on default port 8080, and IDE eclipse for REST app on same port, so it doent work? is it possible to use grail plugin  for eclipse so you will only have one IDE or can you use two, what is best practice ?

Comment: Why not to use different ports? or run on same appserver under different contexts?

Comment: Yes, you need to run them on different ports.  One one app should run on each port.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on how much control you have over the 2 apps and how they have been designed.

First choice is to create a service class in your grails app that communicates with the other app using REST. You could use something like Spring's RestTemplate. The data is then passed to the Controller layer and into your front end JSP/GSP.

If the RESTful application has been designed in such a way that the RESTful layer can be separated from the business layer, then you could add a jar of the business layer to the grails app as a dependency. In this case you would just change the Service class to talk to the jar instead of the RESTful service.

Another option is to have the browser talk to the REST layer directly using JavaScript. This should work as they come from the same server.

Comment: The RESTfull app is separated from the buisnesslayer just got a dependency to it in the pom.xml,  i have made a service class in grails app that should communicate with the RESTfull app in eclipse, but both apps requires tomcat and when i run grails app it will not work beacuse the tomcat is ready used by RESTfull app  and same goes the other way around, both apps work independent but together it is a problem. this work in the web browser http://localhost:8080/backendservice/user for POST for the REST app.

Comment: is your problem to do with deployment while developing or a design issue for the final application deployment?

Comment: I think it is for the final application deployment, , in STS the call is just a regular client call and response to recieve it back like this     Client c = Client.create()
  WebResource webR=c.resource(Uri)
  ClientResponse response=c.resource(Uri).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).
  post(ClientResponse.class,user.toString())
  
  int status = response.getStatus()